# How to correctly create a second window in pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm trying to open a second window beside my mainwindow on a button click and display a tablewidget on it with some data. When I open the window it raises

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'openTable'
```

The mainwindow was created with Qt Designer and converted the ui file with pyuic4. How do I do this correctly correct so that the error is not raised?

**The button calls function:**

```
def showCliplist(self):
    data = self.metadata_list
    luts = self.lutlist
    selected_lut = self.LUTBox.currentIndex()
    openTable = ClipListViewer(data,luts,selected_lut)
    self.openTable.show()
```

**New window class:**

```
class ClipListViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, data, luts, selected_lut, parent = None):
        super(ClipListViewer,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Cliplist')
        self.resize(900,600)
        self.metadata = data
        self.curentluts = luts
        self.choosenlut = selected_lut

        y_count = len(self.metadata)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(y_count,6)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Clip', 'Videocodec', 'FPS', 'Audiocodec', 'Start Timecode', 'LUT'])
        x = y = 0
        for items in self.metadata:
            for entry in items:
                #print entry
                self.table.setItem(y, x, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(entry))
                self.table.resizeColumnToContents(x)
                x += 1
            self.comb = QtGui.QComboBox()
            for lutname in self.curentluts:
                self.comb.addItem(lutname)
                self.comb.setCurrentIndex(self.choosenlut)
            self.table.setCellWidget(y, 5, self.comb)
            self.table.setColumnWidth(5,  230)
            y += 1
            x = 0

        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):  #check if window was closed
        print "Cliplist Window was closed! "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviews your code completed, OK, let's me explain.

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'openTable'
```

**This error says**, "I not have self.openTable in class Ui_MainWindow (That true because your have create own method)".

**Why ?** : Because a problem is in line this;

```
def showCliplist(self):
    data = self.metadata_list
    luts = self.lutlist
    selected_lut = self.LUTBox.currentIndex()
    openTable = ClipListViewer(data,luts,selected_lut) # <- (1) THIS LINE
    self.openTable.show() # <- (2) THIS LINE
```

In (1), your create your second widget in to `openTable` (Not `self.openTable`).
This line we have this object in `openTable` (Not `self.openTable`).
Then (2), your call `QtGui.QWidget.show(self)` to show widget of  `self.openTable` (Not `openTable`). It's should be error because we don't have variable `self.openTable`. To fix it your should use same name variable, Like this;

```
def showCliplist(self):
    data = self.metadata_list
    luts = self.lutlist
    selected_lut = self.LUTBox.currentIndex()
    self.openTable = ClipListViewer(data,luts,selected_lut) # <- FIX THIS LINE !
    self.openTable.show() # <- (2) THIS LINE
```

**Why** second widget is show before I call `self.openTable.show()`?

**Answer** : Your can see in second widget initiate in last line of code your see `QtGui.QWidget.show(self)` has be call before end of initiate;

```
class ClipListViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, data, luts, selected_lut, parent = None):
        super(ClipListViewer,self).__init__()
        .
        .
        .
        self.show() # <- THIS LINE
```

---

Regards,

Comment: THX a lot! Everything fine now!